# How .NET applications compiled with old .NET Framework Assemblies still be able resolve newer .NET Framework assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have been looking for an answer to that but so far I have not been able to. For those who are not familiar with the basis of my question, here is some explanation to that.

### Context

You can have two types of assembly in .NET when it comes to naming your assemblies:

1. Strong-named Assemblies
2. Simple-named Assemblies (aka Weakly-named Assemblies as coined by Jeffrey Richter in his CLR via C# book).

Unlike Simple-named Assemblies, the Strong-named assemblies are signed with a public/private key. Related to my question, one of the benefits of signing the assembly is the following:

Now the version number of your assembly becomes important. Assemblies
contain a static reference to other assemblies that they use the types of. When they reference a strong-named assembly, you must give them
that same exact assembly with the exact signature (name, version,
culture, and public key token). Otherwise, the fusion assembly loader
will fail at resolving it.

Also, strong-named assemblies can only reference other strong-named assemblies but not simple-named assemblies.

## Question

Based on what I have described, I also expect the same rules to be applied to referencing .NET Framework assemblies. Meaning that my assemblies will search for exact versions of the referenced assemblies that are shipped with a .NET Framework that I originally used the assemblies of in my compiled application. However, when you upgrade from .NET 4.5 to 4.7, without re-compiling your application, your application is still working and supposed to be working. How is that possible and how does Microsoft manages that? Do they apply an exception to their assemblies in the fusion loader so that it always loads the latest .NET Framework assemblies for user-developed applications? Does it use a `bindingRedirect` internally for each possible old version to new version? Do they use publishers policies?

I feel like the answer is hidden in this text:

> **The runtime uses the following steps to resolve an assembly reference:**
>
> 1. Determines the correct assembly version by examining applicable
>      configuration files, including the application configuration file,
>      publisher policy file, and machine configuration file. If the
>      configuration file is located on a remote machine, the runtime must
>      locate and download the application configuration file first.
> 2. ... -- [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)

## Other notes:

#### Specific Version

For some, there is a misconception about `Specific Version = true` flag, which can be changed in Visual Studio when referencing an assembly. This flag is for compile-time checking only and has nothing to do with the runtime assembly resolution. In fact, the assembly will still have the strong name including assembly name, version, and public key token (if exists).

#### An Extra Quick Question: By Default?

> By default, the runtime attempts to bind with the exact version of an
>   assembly that the application was built with.

says, Microsoft. It confuses me a little bit. Does it mean that version number is important for both weakly-named and strong-named assemblies to get resolved? For instance, if I drop a weakly-named assembly with an incremented version number, then will it not be resolved by other assemblies that are referencing the older version of it?

Comment: I would have thought it was publisher policies as they are also strong-named; GAC'd and associated with the original assembly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: .NET Framework 4+ is updated in-place. That means new version of .NET Framework replace old one. And new assemblies have the same version number as old ones.